# When added to "gulp", "Critical" gives the error Error: Penthouse timed out after 180s

Tags: css, gulp

I want to add [critical](https://github.com/addyosmani/critical/blob/master/README.md) to build critical css, but all attempts fail. Gives an error
Here is the problem code

```
import gulp from "gulp";
import { stream as critical } from 'critical';

export const criticalCss = () => {
   return gulp.src(app.path.build.html + "*.html")
      .pipe(app.plugins.plumber(
         app.plugins.notify.onError({
            title: "HTML",
            message: "Error: <%= error.message %>"
         }))
      )
      .pipe(critical({
         base: './docs', 
         inline: true,
         css: app.path.build.css + 'style.min.css', 
         dimensions: [{
            width: 320,
            height: 480
         }, {
            width: 768,
            height: 1024
         }, {
            width: 1920,
            height: 960
         }],
         penthouse: {
            timeout: 180000
         },
         //ignore: ['font-face']
      }))
      .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.html));
}
```

I added the task to the collection like this

```
const mainTasks = gulp.series(fonts, gulp.parallel(copy, html, scss, js, images, svgSpriteTask));
const build = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, criticalCss);
```

Here is the error

> [10:14:30] gulp-notify: [HTML] Error: Penthouse timed out after 180s.

Increased processing time, does not help